# Как усреднить значения по точным группам времени?

Tags: python

Есть массив

```
data = [
   {"timestamp": 1604029392, "val": 23.88},
   {"timestamp": 1604028792, "val": 28.99},
   {"timestamp": 1604028192, "val": 22.20},
   {"timestamp": 1604027592, "val": 29.02},
   {"timestamp": 1604026992, "val": 28.46},
   {"timestamp": 1604026392, "val": 20.67},
   {"timestamp": 1604025792, "val": 20.80},
   {"timestamp": 1604025192, "val": 22.51},
   {"timestamp": 1604024592, "val": 23.72},
   {"timestamp": 1604023992, "val": 28.37},
   {"timestamp": 1604023392, "val": 22.33},
   {"timestamp": 1604022792, "val": 21.80},
   {"timestamp": 1604022192, "val": 24.11},
   {"timestamp": 1604021592, "val": 26.96},
   {"timestamp": 1604020992, "val": 27.22},
   {"timestamp": 1604020392, "val": 21.24},
   {"timestamp": 1604019792, "val": 20.75},
   {"timestamp": 1604019192, "val": 21.81},
   {"timestamp": 1604018592, "val": 20.08},
   {"timestamp": 1604017992, "val": 24.58},
   {"timestamp": 1604017392, "val": 28.68},
   {"timestamp": 1604016792, "val": 29.03},
   {"timestamp": 1604016192, "val": 29.84},
   {"timestamp": 1604015592, "val": 29.30},
   {"timestamp": 1604014992, "val": 21.05},
   {"timestamp": 1604014392, "val": 21.68},
   {"timestamp": 1604013792, "val": 25.40},
   {"timestamp": 1604013192, "val": 29.71},
   {"timestamp": 1604012592, "val": 24.74},
   {"timestamp": 1604011992, "val": 28.97},
   {"timestamp": 1604011392, "val": 25.45},
   {"timestamp": 1604010792, "val": 22.80},
   {"timestamp": 1604010192, "val": 29.69},
   {"timestamp": 1604009592, "val": 25.21},
   {"timestamp": 1604008992, "val": 29.52},
   {"timestamp": 1604008392, "val": 27.05},
   {"timestamp": 1604007792, "val": 22.23},
   {"timestamp": 1604007192, "val": 26.83},
   {"timestamp": 1604006592, "val": 29.44},
   {"timestamp": 1604005992, "val": 26.33},
   {"timestamp": 1604005392, "val": 20.59},
   {"timestamp": 1604004792, "val": 23.01},
   {"timestamp": 1604004192, "val": 20.93},
   {"timestamp": 1604003592, "val": 26.58},
   {"timestamp": 1604002992, "val": 29.65},
   {"timestamp": 1604002392, "val": 27.04},
   {"timestamp": 1604001792, "val": 27.91},
   {"timestamp": 1604001192, "val": 28.34},
   {"timestamp": 1604000592, "val": 29.63},
   {"timestamp": 1603999992, "val": 20.81},
   {"timestamp": 1603999392, "val": 25.77},
   {"timestamp": 1603998792, "val": 21.31},
   {"timestamp": 1603998192, "val": 21.18},
   {"timestamp": 1603997592, "val": 23.52},
   {"timestamp": 1603996992, "val": 22.35},
   {"timestamp": 1603996392, "val": 20.99},
   {"timestamp": 1603995792, "val": 27.41},
   {"timestamp": 1603995192, "val": 21.08},
   {"timestamp": 1603994592, "val": 26.19},
   {"timestamp": 1603993992, "val": 23.32},
   {"timestamp": 1603993392, "val": 28.46},
   {"timestamp": 1603992792, "val": 24.04},
   {"timestamp": 1603992192, "val": 28.37},
   {"timestamp": 1603991592, "val": 22.59},
   {"timestamp": 1603990992, "val": 27.60},
   {"timestamp": 1603990392, "val": 22.78},
   {"timestamp": 1603989792, "val": 21.05},
   {"timestamp": 1603989192, "val": 28.48},
   {"timestamp": 1603988592, "val": 23.44},
   {"timestamp": 1603987992, "val": 22.00},
   {"timestamp": 1603987392, "val": 22.57},
   {"timestamp": 1603986792, "val": 22.96},
   {"timestamp": 1603986192, "val": 27.96},
   {"timestamp": 1603985592, "val": 26.46},
   {"timestamp": 1603984992, "val": 24.10},
   {"timestamp": 1603984392, "val": 28.32},
   {"timestamp": 1603983792, "val": 21.27},
   {"timestamp": 1603983192, "val": 27.93},
   {"timestamp": 1603982592, "val": 20.47},
   {"timestamp": 1603981992, "val": 21.16},
   {"timestamp": 1603981392, "val": 26.48},
   {"timestamp": 1603980792, "val": 24.69},
   {"timestamp": 1603980192, "val": 24.16},
   {"timestamp": 1603979592, "val": 23.41},
   {"timestamp": 1603978992, "val": 27.45},
   {"timestamp": 1603978392, "val": 25.15},
   {"timestamp": 1603977792, "val": 26.00},
   {"timestamp": 1603977192, "val": 23.48},
   {"timestamp": 1603976592, "val": 29.27},
   {"timestamp": 1603975992, "val": 28.72},
   {"timestamp": 1603975392, "val": 22.39},
   {"timestamp": 1603974792, "val": 24.94},
   {"timestamp": 1603974192, "val": 22.12},
   {"timestamp": 1603973592, "val": 20.75},
   {"timestamp": 1603972992, "val": 28.00},
   {"timestamp": 1603972392, "val": 24.77},
   {"timestamp": 1603971792, "val": 25.98},
   {"timestamp": 1603971192, "val": 24.46},
   {"timestamp": 1603970592, "val": 29.23},
   {"timestamp": 1603969992, "val": 29.09},
   {"timestamp": 1603969392, "val": 21.12},
   {"timestamp": 1603968792, "val": 20.82},
   {"timestamp": 1603968192, "val": 28.81},
   {"timestamp": 1603967592, "val": 20.29},
   {"timestamp": 1603966992, "val": 28.82},
   {"timestamp": 1603966392, "val": 25.81},
   {"timestamp": 1603965792, "val": 28.11},
   {"timestamp": 1603965192, "val": 28.74},
   {"timestamp": 1603964592, "val": 28.73},
   {"timestamp": 1603963992, "val": 26.85},
   {"timestamp": 1603963392, "val": 26.63},
   {"timestamp": 1603962792, "val": 29.83},
   {"timestamp": 1603962192, "val": 25.30},
   {"timestamp": 1603961592, "val": 29.42},
   {"timestamp": 1603960992, "val": 20.78},
   {"timestamp": 1603960392, "val": 28.60},
   {"timestamp": 1603959792, "val": 20.11},
   {"timestamp": 1603959192, "val": 27.56},
   {"timestamp": 1603958592, "val": 28.56},
   {"timestamp": 1603957992, "val": 25.85},
   {"timestamp": 1603957392, "val": 25.07},
   {"timestamp": 1603956792, "val": 28.39},
   {"timestamp": 1603956192, "val": 22.40},
   {"timestamp": 1603955592, "val": 29.27},
   {"timestamp": 1603954992, "val": 23.59},
   {"timestamp": 1603954392, "val": 25.85},
   {"timestamp": 1603953792, "val": 22.03},
   {"timestamp": 1603953192, "val": 28.38},
   {"timestamp": 1603952592, "val": 29.77},
   {"timestamp": 1603951992, "val": 23.33},
   {"timestamp": 1603951392, "val": 23.05},
   {"timestamp": 1603950792, "val": 29.68},
   {"timestamp": 1603950192, "val": 29.34},
   {"timestamp": 1603949592, "val": 28.74},
   {"timestamp": 1603948992, "val": 24.90},
   {"timestamp": 1603948392, "val": 22.56},
   {"timestamp": 1603947792, "val": 27.37},
   {"timestamp": 1603947192, "val": 26.80},
   {"timestamp": 1603946592, "val": 20.18},
   {"timestamp": 1603945992, "val": 28.89},
   {"timestamp": 1603945392, "val": 27.89},
   {"timestamp": 1603944792, "val": 26.54},
   {"timestamp": 1603944192, "val": 27.17},
   {"timestamp": 1603943592, "val": 29.96}
]
```

Массив берется из БД за последний промежуток, там сохранены результаты измерения температуры с интервалом примерно 30-50 секунд

Надо усреднить значения с шагом кратным заданному времени.

Например сейчас [5 марта 17:12]

В массиве data окажется выборка от [5 марта 17:12] до [4 марта 17:12]

Нужно будет создать массив где время будет с точным шагом, 17:00, 16:00, 15:00,... и до 17:00 прошлого дня

т.е. первое значение будет усреднено всего за 12 последних минут, но будет показано как за 17:00

А у последнего лишние 12 минут будут выкинуты

Comment: Наверное через `Pandas` проще делать, но как конкретно сходу не подскажу. Но там всё для этого есть.

Comment: Если бы вы привели пример исходных данных, нам бы было в разы легче вам ответить. Сейчас же мне просо лень и нету особо времени генерировать за вас таблицу с данными.

Comment: @strawdog я сгенерировал таблицу за сутки с шагом 10 минут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать с помощью модуля `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(data, key=lambda x: x["timestamp"])) # data-ваш список словарей
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit="s")

df_24h = df[df["timestamp"]>=(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=24))]
res = df_24h.groupby(df["timestamp"].dt.hour).mean()
```

тогда `res` будет:

```
                 val
timestamp           
0          25.670000
1          23.680000
2          23.066667
3          26.510000
8          25.100000
9          27.680000
10         25.443333
11         25.775000
12         24.486667
13         25.793333
14         24.148333
15         25.178333
16         23.386667
17         25.730000
18         23.590000
19         24.506667
20         25.853333
21         25.411667
22         26.940000
23         25.313333
```

(здесь 20 значений, а не 24, потому что я делал выборку от моего текущего времени, и данных в data просто не хватило.)

либо, если вам нужен не датафрейм, а именно список, то так можно добавить конвертацию:

```
res.values.tolist()
```

что даст, соответственно:

```
[[25.67],
 [23.679999999999996],
 [23.066666666666666],
 [26.51],
 [25.1],
 [27.679999999999996],
 [25.44333333333333],
 [25.775000000000002],
 [24.486666666666668],
 [25.793333333333333],
 [24.14833333333333],
 [25.178333333333338],
 [23.386666666666667],
 [25.73],
 [23.59],
 [24.506666666666664],
 [25.853333333333328],
 [25.411666666666665],
 [26.939999999999998],
 [25.313333333333333]]
```

Comment: заменил datetime.datetime.now() на data[0]["timestamp"]

Но он как-то странно выдает, если поставить в первый элемент val = 10000, то выброс происходит на res[3], а не res[0]

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы хотели получить от data[0]["timestamp"] - если вам нужно конкретное значение из датафрейма, то для этого используются методы loc и iloc.

Answer (score 1):

если аппроксимировать не надо, то можно сделать так:

```
data = [{'time': 10, 'val': 15}, {'time': 18, 'val': 15}, {'time': 13, 'val': 18}]

data_new = []

for time in range(8, 20, 2):
    count = 0
    sum = 0

    for obj in data:
        if time <= obj['time'] < time + 2:
            count += 1
            sum += obj['val']

    data_new.append((time, 0 if count == 0 else sum / count))

print(data_new)
```

ну или так:

```
data_new = []

for time in range(8, 20, 2):
    local = [obj['val'] for obj in data if time <= obj['time'] < time + 2]
    data_new.append((time, 0 if len(local) == 0 else sum(local) / len(local)))
```